# Mapping aesthetics ( color fill and intervals )

Tags: r, ggplot2, arguments, mapping, aesthetics

I am doing a map of the united states , but I wanted to change the color of the states fill , however when I try to do it it only changes the colors of the lines between the states and not the state :(

Can anyone tell me how to change the color feature and also how can I add color intervals to the map.

Here is my code : [image]

And the map that it gives me : [image]

I tried to change the colors of all the map filling but it only changes the color of the line between the states.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064) `fill=` change the color inside the state and `color=` change the color of the lines separating states.

Answer (score 0):

@sikimimi. You can change your color palette by adding a scales control, `scale_fill...`, to your code.

For example, in `scale_fill_gradient()` you can set a `low` and `high` color value.

The [ggplot reference](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/index.html) has a complete list of these controls.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where can I find the color references ? Because in the argument example they have wirtten a reference for the light and the dark blue :)